# How to properly interpret coolant levels in the reservoir of my van?

Tags: ford, coolant, overheating

I just slapped a new radator into my Ford van (1998 5.4 v8 triton 2 valve).

But somethin unexpected is happenin now.

You see... I swears I remember before this radator replacement operation, when the vehicle was at the operational temp, the coolant reservoir showed the coolant level as relatively low.  Then when the vehicle cools, the level reads higher up.

But now it seems to be the opposite -- when the vehicle is warmed up the level actually rises up higher.

Ain't that a bit suspect?

I'm scared there is mystery bubbles inside the engine causin isolated weather patterns and that she is gonna blow and empty my bank account.  I thank I may a done somethin wrong when I slapped that radator in her.

Somebody please verify this basic knowledge.  Thank you.

Comment: Water expands when hot, so I would expect the level to rise, not fall.

Comment: Well that sound like the answer.  Before I slapped my new radator in there it was doin the opposite... I wonder if that is because it didn't have no pressure before... even though I don't know why that would cause that... but the basic circumstances was different anyhow.  And now it's workin textbook style so that great!